# Хостинг телеграм-бота на гугл облаке

Tags: telegram-bot, hosting, облако

Я написал тг-бота на питоне, но у меня нет денег на хостинг. Можно как-то его хостить на облаке гугл? Или как-то по другому бесплатно это делать?

Comment: [«на облаке гугл»](https://cloud.google.com/python?hl=ru) это будет тоже отнюдь не бесплатно.

Comment: heroku? pythonanywhere?

Comment: у oracle есть always free виртуалки

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тексту вопроса, вы под гугл-облаком имели в виду гугл-диск.

У гугл-диска нет функционала хостинга, тем более ещё и с питоном. Гугл-диск - сервис хранения.

Статей в интернете по бесплатным хостингам достаточно, нужно лишь потратить немного времени на просмотр результатов запроса `бесплатный хостинг для python бота`. На данный момент могу вспомнить только *PythonAyware*, но к сожалению, существует ли он сейчас и бесплатен ли, не знаю.

Также, если нагрузка на бота маленькая, хостить можно хоть дома, если есть возможность обеспечить работу машины в нужные промежутки времени.

Comment: *У гугл-облака нет функционала хостинга … Гугл-облако предназначено для хранения.* — [вообще там много чего предлагают](https://cloud.google.com/solutions) например, [web-hosting](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-hosting). брешут, небось.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо за наводку. не знал, что `google cloud` не равно `google drive`